GET request times for apartments.com, but website is not down
I am trying to make a GET requests to https://apartments.com. However, the request is just timing out or hanging forever. The page loads just fine in the browser, so the web server isn't just down.
I'm a web developer, so I've worked with the requests module a lot in the past as well as my own web servers, and it was my understanding that unless the server is down, it should always be returning something. If I'm just missing a specific header or cookie I'd expect at least a 403 error.
Other websites work perfectly fine, and I run into this issue on different machines on different networks, so the issue probably isn't with my firewall or connection or anything. The error occurs with both Python and curl. How can I fix this?
My Python code is as follows:
import requests

url = "https://www.apartments.com/" # Any path on this domain has this issue.
url = "https://www.apartments.com/"
escaped_time_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a+%b+%d+%Y+%H___%M___%S+GMT-0600+(Mountain+Daylight+Time)").replace("___", "%3A")
print(escaped_time_string)
headers = { # These are the headers that were sent by the browser when I visited the website. I have tried other values for User-Agent, but nothing changes.
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0",
    "Host": "www.apartments.com",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": f"cb=1; cul=en-US; ab=%7b%22e%22%3atrue%2c%22r%22%3a%5b%5d%7d; afe=%7b%22e%22%3afalse%7d; fso=%7b%22e%22%3afalse%7d; sr=%7B%22Width%22%3A2560%2C%22Height%22%3A1279%2C%22PixelRatio%22%3A1%7D; _ga=GA1.2.1587172952.1719086370; _gid=GA1.2.2141307871.1719086370; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp={escaped_time_string}&version=202401.2.0&browserGpcFlag=0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=7bc5ce4e-ac96-493a-bcbb-c4a1f2084786&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; gip=%7b%22Display%22%3a%22Orem%2c+UT%22%2c%22GeographyType%22%3a2%2c%22Address%22%3a%7b%22City%22%3a%22Orem%22%2c%22CountryCode%22%3a%22US%22%2c%22State%22%3a%22UT%22%7d%2c%22Location%22%3a%7b%22Latitude%22%3a40.3142%2c%22Longitude%22%3a-111.7099%7d%2c%22IsPmcSearchByCityState%22%3afalse%7d; akaalb_www_apartments_com_main=1719122615~op=apartments_Prd_Edge_US:www_apartments_com_LAX|~rv=77~m=www_apartments_com_LAX:0|~os=0847b47fe1c72dfaedb786f1e8b4b630~id=6fe4004a168575354c8284d8b9dcdec9; ak_bmsc=58307435F65C23FE0EBD31E15CF76945~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQRqfLF+IFxjaQAQAApWx6Qxji3KakC+xNTdsIM+85gJPMwEo498Se+B3+ugjIZV6wiX2p63okc8LKIQYXV3UJjNcRZe05q8LM3FXGCivYqWKHk1795v1Ismu17ai6hO2NRmiHUnW7LM9WHwZsYyJFqGGeRfs9K2JX3abwcljSCXK55n2XBmdryImrz93faWCWIJqy3fCyQGGJoh8iScFiiegqL4zJg14yojxdLOBSJsVXPBnH0F2uLcs5rNpkgGZ/88uFKf66BOU340ir2Yr9QNi3CV5+90STD0hHITUhbIoG7l5Oc7991FZYZFUrj1IWT9vxnwyJOk76yYqdkN5oRuT3GO1WsPZDXp/7sh6e9gSDsAcQRdhIO3eLP4p6A5fkzc5hqogez5F01U4=; _gat=1; bm_sv=F96ACBC1FDF433C48190DCBABDE1376B~YAAQRqfLFx0GxjaQAQAAdm96QxjvIM6idZiwJvdJ3swWH5GcroUfVp9H3HRvvKzoNhUaYrtPnpUOjnfNVrLvVCN+PZNmaO/efw9Id7eOmJ9nDqVBI7g4q1+S4Y7YYd9mmE1wXAy6fgIEBW4I0aD2vfMXXs768jB4P2D26X94iUlSYjZyWSDqVP3p2oBHV+/TUUwU91FAJMXON8j+hMPXaWF74ogpw4kEWWKme2ireco1yRfqVEeRxXShohFdbhheFWgbwg==~1",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Priority": "u=1",
    "TE": "trailers"
}

req = requests.get(url, timeout=10, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)

req = None
try:
    req = requests.get(url, timeout=10, allow_redirects=True)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print("Timed out")

if req:
    print(req.text)

This curl command yields the same results:
curl https://apartments.com
Most headers are constant every time my browser accesses the page, but the cookie header has parts that changes every time. One of them includes the current time, which is an easy fix. But it also includes values for bm_sv and bm_mi. I don't have much experience with cookies but they seem to include location data so they might be the issue.

Apparently, the website decided you're a robot (which you are) and chose not to respond.

Have you tried providing custom request headers, like user-agent? Most servers typically care a lot about stuff like that.

sometimes using even fake User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 can help - but sometimes it needs full User-Agent from real web browser. Of course page can check also other other headers. especially cookies (session ID), But first you have to check if page can work when you turn off JavaScript in browser. If it needs JavaScript then requests and BS can be useless because they can't run JavaScript and it may need Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

@JohnGordon I didn't see anything in the robots.txt that would make this not okay. And I have tried several user-agent headers, but nothing was making any changes. I will edit the question to make that more clear.

if you used some headers then show it in code - so we could test it too. You have to show all details in question because we can't see your computer and we can't read in your mind.

I had tried a variety but because it didn't make a difference I removed them to make the code less cluttered. It's not letting me edit the post right now (says to review a suggested edit but doesn't actually have any suggested edits to review) but later if I can I will add that information

if this problem exists on other computers then maybe it blocks some range of IPs or all connections from your country.

I tried copying the exact headers my browser sends, and the cookie header has parts that changes every time. One of them includes the current time, which is an easy fix. But it also includes values for bm_sv and bm_mi. I don't have much experience with cookies but they seem to include location data so they might be the issue.

Sometimes portals check header User-Agent to check if it web browser,
or to send different content for different browsers or different devices (desktop, table, phone).
Some send something even if program sends wrong User-Agent but some pages block access.
requests sends something like python/requests ... as User-Agent
Sometimes can help even fake Mozilla/5.0 but this page needed value from real web browser. If you visit page http://httpbin.org/get then you can see what your browser sends to server and you can use it.
I used
headers = {
    #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0',
}

req = requests.get(url, timeout=10, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)

and it gives me some data.
But I didn't check if it is useful HTML or some JavaScript or Captcha.

If you already tested User-Agent and you still can't access in code then maybe server remember you (using other details) and it may need to use more complex system - e.g. proxy to change IP.
OR it may need to use all information which you find in real web browser (in headers).
OR it may need to use Selenium with real web browser.

Thanks for the response. I'd tried the user-agent header as I said in the original question (but definitely could have made clearer) but it didn't work. This one is also not changing anything for me.

well, you said that you used different headers but you didn't show what values you used. For me don't worke Mozilla/5.0 but works Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0 - so full value is important for this page. But as I said in last line - you could made so many wrong connections so web page put you on blacklist and it doesn't connect even if you use correct User-Agent. And this may need to use proxy to change IP. OR it may need to use all information which you find in real web browser (in headers). OR it may need to use Selenium with real web browser.

I had used a variety of headers. I just tried that one on a network I hadn't used yet (so new IP address) and it didn't work either.

code works for me with full user-agent - so I can't reproduce your problem - so I can't help you more. It seems you have bigger problem (which we can't reproduce so we can't say what can be the problem)

the only idea - try with Selenium because server may have more complex system which can block different connection in different situations. Maybe it uses some Artificial Intelligence which decide who is blocked.

Selenium seems to be working. I was hoping to be able to host this and have it run once a day automatically, but it doesn't seem like that will be an option. Thank you for the help!

why? you can still run it automatically with Selenium - it can run with option --headless so it can run on server without graphics interface. OR if server use Linux then it can use xvfb - fake graphics interface. Python has even module xvfbwrapper to activate this fake graphics interface. How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?

i'm using the headless option, but it still requires a browser to be installed, no? i'm not sure if any remote providers would have that accessible

yes headless still need to install browser. If remote server gives access by ssh then it usually allow to install own programs in own folder. It allows to upload own file/program  and run it without installation.

So I was able to replicate the issue you were experiencing. Here are some tips you can try out to scrape the site. First you want to make sure to play around with headers, previous answers were on the right track.
I don't have any way of proving my theory but I firmly believe that apartments.com black lists specific headers. If you are doing a one time scrape then go into your headers and copy the headers from your internet explorer. I will provide screenshots on how to do this.


Copy and paste whatever you get then look for the user agent value and copy that to your code.
import requests


s = requests.Session()
url = "https://www.apartments.com/" # any path on this domain has this issue

 # headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'}

 headers = {
"Accept": "*/*",
"Host": "www.apartments.com",
# "User-Agent": "com.apple.WebKit.Networking/19618.2.12.11.6 CFNetwork/1496.0.7 Darwin/23.5.0",
'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Connection": "keep-alive"
 }
 req = s.get(url, headers=headers) # tried a variety of headers to pretend it's a browser, nothing changes
 print(req.text)

If you are trying to automate a scrape I encourage you get a more updated list of headers that may not be blocked from apartments.com and use proxies. A popular site like that will have a full team of devs trying to figure out new ways to deter web scraping of their site.
I was able to get some content from it and the code was not timing out. In short find more updated headers rather then the generic ones you get from a library like fake_useragent.
Please make sure you are looking at the robots.txt site of apartments.com to scrape in accordance to their policy. They have an api you can use to get content from their site. Hope this helps!
